# Extracting URIs from RDF web page in Java using Jena Library

Tags: java, xml-parsing, web-crawler, rdf, jena

I have written following code for extratcting URIs from a web page with content type `application/rdf-xml` for Linked Data application.

```
public static void test(String url) {
    try {
        Model read = ModelFactory.createDefaultModel().read(url);
        System.out.println("to go");
        StmtIterator si;
        si = read.listStatements();
        System.out.println("to go");
        while(si.hasNext()) {
            Statement s=si.nextStatement();
            Resource r=s.getSubject();
            Property p=s.getPredicate();
            RDFNode o=s.getObject();
            System.out.println(r.getURI());
            System.out.println(p.getURI());
            System.out.println(o.asResource().getURI());
        }
    }
    catch(JenaException | NoSuchElementException c) {}
}
```

But for the input

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<rdf:RDF xmlns:rdf="http://www.w3.org/1999/02/22-rdf-syntax-ns#"
    xmlns:dc="http://purl.org/dc/elements/1.1/" xmlns:ex="http://example.org/stuff/1.0/">
    <rdf:Description rdf:about="http://www.w3.org/TR/rdf-syntax-grammar"
        dc:title="RDF/XML Syntax Specification (Revised)">
        <ex:editor>
            <rdf:Description ex:fullName="Dave Beckett">
                <ex:homePage rdf:resource="http://purl.org/net/dajobe/" />
            </rdf:Description>
        </ex:editor>
    </rdf:Description>
</rdf:RDF>
```

The output is :

```
Subject URI is http://www.w3.org/TR/rdf-syntax-grammar
Predicate  URI is http://example.org/stuff/1.0/editor
Object URI is null
Subject URI is http://www.w3.org/TR/rdf-syntax-grammar
Predicate  URI is http://purl.org/dc/elements/1.1/title
Website is read
```

I require in the output all the URIs present on that page to build a web crawler for RDF pages.
I require all following links in output:

```
       http://www.w3.org/TR/rdf-syntax-grammar
       http://example.org/stuff/1.0/editor
       http://purl.org/net/dajobe
       http://example.org/stuff/1.0/fullName
       http://www.w3.org/TR/rdf-syntax-grammar
       http://purl.org/dc/elements/1.1/title
```

Comment: Put the XML online and give us the URL

Comment: Also, you are not supposed to iterate through all the triples manually. See [this old answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/12236809/315306) to get a brief introduction to the query language that you are supposed to use in Jena to extract information from a serialized model

Comment: Delete these two useless comments, and edit your question providing the desired output, because I cannot fully understand your question

Comment: ok. i have done it.and edited in the question itself

Comment: Better, still I don't understand **which page** you want to extract URLs from. I hope you know that URL in RDF are not used for location but for identification...

Comment: the page I have specified by argument to the function test i.e String url="http://www.w3.org/TR/REC-rdf-syntax/example04.rdf"

Comment: hey.Raffaele it is not showing statements for blank nodes

Comment: **Who** is not showing **what**? And **where**?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Minor mistake: you mean `application/rdf+xml` (note the plus).

Anyway, your problem is very simple:

```
catch(JenaException | NoSuchElementException c) {}
```

Bad! You're missing the error thrown here, and the output is being truncated:

```
System.out.println(o.asResource().getURI());
```

`o` *isn't* always a resource, and this will break on the triple

```
<http://www.w3.org/TR/rdf-syntax-grammar> dc:title "RDF/XML Syntax ..."
```

so you need to guard against that:

```
if (o.isResource()) System.out.println(o.asResource().getURI());
```

or even more specific:

```
if (o.isURIResource()) System.out.println(o.asResource().getURI());
```

which will skip the `null` output you see for `ex:editor`.

Now write one thousand times *I will not swallow exceptions* :-)

Answer (score 1):

No, you don't understand what RDF is used for. A crawler is a program designed to retrieve online content and index it. A simple crawler can be fed with a HTML document and it will download (maybe recursively) all the documents mentioned in the `href` attributes of `<a>` elements.

RDF is full of URLs, so you may think it's perfect to feed a crawler, but unfortunately URL in an RDF document are not intended to retrieve other documents. Examples:

- http://example.org/stuff/1.0/editor 404 not found
- http://purl.org/net/dajobe 302 Moved Temporarily
- http://example.org/stuff/1.0/fullName 404 not found
- http://www.w3.org/TR/rdf-syntax-grammar 301 Moved Permanently
- http://purl.org/dc/elements/1.1/title 302 Moved Temporarily

Can it be a coincidence? I don't think so. The fact is that RDF is intended to *describe the real world* and it happens that it can be serialized in XML form, but XML is not [the only available serialization](http://jena.apache.org/tutorials/sparql_data.html).

So, what are URLs used for in a document? They are used **to name thing**. How many John do you know? Possibly dozens, and still thousands of John's exist... However, if I own the domain `example.com` I can use the URL `http://example.com/friends/John` to refer to my friend named John. RDF can be used to describe that your friend John works at 123, Abc avenue, through two URLs and a string

```
"http://me.com/John"   "http://me.com/works_at"   "123, Abc avenue"
```

this is referred to as a *triple*, and URLs contained in it are not meant to point so something retrievable via a TCP socket and a client which understands the HTTP protocol. Note that both your friend (John) **and the predicate** (works at) are referenced in the triple via a URL. But if your try those URLs in the browser you'll get nothing.

I don't know why you are building your crawler and what it is supposed to do, but certainly RDF is not what you need to do your job.

Comment: hey according to Tim Berner Lee's four principle for linked data(http://www.w3.org/DesignIssues/LinkedData.html) .It should retrieve description about the resource which URI represents.

Comment: It *should*. Unfortunately it *won't*. Try it yourself if you don't trust. And, even if a HTML document is present at that URL, it will describe, for example, the `http://ma.com/works_at` predicate, but in some totally proprietary format (table? divs? xml? other?) So how do you plan to use it?

Comment: hey..According to Linked Data, on referncing a URI it should retrieve HTML or RDF/XML description depending on header you send in for request. I want to retrieve RDF/XML description and if this RDF/XML description contains more URIs, I want to crawl these URIs.

Comment: I think you should grab a real RDF document and test your program against it, instead of making assumptions about "linked data" based on what you read on somewhere and a demo XML which lists 4 triples. Anyway, at some point you'll get what I mean. Good luck with your project